# ROW_NUMBER Constraint Against a View

Tags: mysql, view, row-number

I'm testing a simple query section that runs from a view instead of a table. When I leave out the ROW_NUMBER line, the query returns results.  With this line active, I just get NULL results.  Is there some restriction against doing these kinds of operations on a view?

```
SELECT
    `VMC Savings`,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY `VMC Savings`) AS row_n
FROM v_vmc_summary
```

Result with ROW_NUMBER code:
[image]

Result with ROW_NUMBER commented out:
[image]

Comment: Adding a row_number clause should not impact the rows returned by a query - it's not clear what you mean by NULL results, can you add some sample data or create a FIDDLE that demonstrates, and include the view definition.

Comment: @Stu By NULL results, I mean that I do get the right number of rows returned with the row number, but the contents of the 'VMC Savings' column is NULL for every row.

Comment: if you partition by the key ofthe table/view do you get the results?  If any one of the VMC Savings values is null it might be causing your problem

Comment: @xQbert That was it!  I added a WHERE `VMC Savings` IS NOT NULL to the query and it now works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

without a partition by every record is evaluated and if null exists; Null will replace every value.

Partition by the complete key or filter out null results.

"Partition by clause is an optional part of Row_Number function and if you don't use it all the records of the result-set will be considered as a part of single record group or a single partition and then ranking functions are applied."

above source: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/rownumber-function-with-partition-by-clause-in-sql-server1

but I believe it applies to mysql as well..

Since it looks at it as a single partition; and NULL exists and null needs special handling... I think there in is the problem.

I suppose you could coalesce(value,0) if you are willing the nulls to be 0.